# How do you explain Raspbian base directory structure? Different than Linux

Tags: raspbian

RPi File Manager directory tree show two tree items
Pi and /

They are on same level.

I am trying to learn how to navigate Linux file structure and was expecting 
"/" as unnamed base only.

Is RPi hierarchy different than Linux and is there a doc explaining this basic hierarchy in RPi?

So the question is irrelevant? Is this marked by robot? Please show me relevant question ?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't see `~/` as the path?

Comment: jacobm not sure what are you asking, but the issue is solved

Comment: If the issue is solved, then I would suggest you accept the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may clear up the confusion, go to the root directory `cd /` (in the terminal) and type `pwd`, then type `ls -la`. Note you will not see the **pi** directory at the same level as the root directory. Now go to the **pi** directory (`cd`) and rerun `pwd`. Note this is as expected under the **/home** directory.

The GUI file manager may appear to show the **pi** directory as a peer, but as the above experiment shows  they are not. They are more like the shortcuts in the windows explorer or file open dialog boxes, and are there to make life easier.

Comment: I can do cd / and see the normal structure , but when i do cd /pi I if I edd new user where it shoud wshow in File manager tree ?do not get any pi pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd pi
bash: cd: pi: No such file or directory
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd /pi
bash: cd: /pi: No such file or directory
pi@raspberrypi:~ $

Comment: @JanHus that is because it is `cd /home/pi` or just `cd` (assuming you are logged in as pi). `cd` only changes to your home directory. `/pi` does not exist. It is displayed that way in filemanager, but it is only a shortcut like desktop and downloads in windows file explorer.

Comment: Ok , got it  root home pi

Comment: SO if I have another user should I see same shortcut in File Manger?

Comment: I would expect so, but it depends on how they implemented it. You could answer that by adding a new user. I would expect one of two things. Either you will see the /pi shortcut or a /user shortcut. Actually you might see neither again depending on how they implemented it.

Comment: I already have another user , but did not want  to muddy the waters  initially. No, I have only Pi user shortcut, but since you  help me to understand this , it is no longer an issue .  .